# Summing data-frame columns from different data-frames

Tags: python, pandas

I have a number of timeseries .csv files that I am reading into a dataframe (df).  I would like to create another data-frame that has the sum of all of these dataframes added together.

Examples of the dataframes are as follows. Example df 1:

```
         date BBG.XASX.ABP.S_price BBG.XASX.ABP.S_pos BBG.XASX.ABP.S_trade \ 
0  2017-09-11            2.8303586                0.0                  0.0   
1  2017-09-12            2.8135189                0.0                  0.0   
2  2017-09-13            2.7829274            86614.0              86614.0   
3  2017-09-14            2.7928042            86614.0                  0.0   
4  2017-09-15            2.8120383            86614.0                  0.0   

  BBG.XASX.ABP.S_cost BBG.XASX.ABP.S_pnl_pre_cost 
0                -0.0                         0.0   
1                -0.0                         0.0    
2    -32.540463966186                         0.0   
3                -0.0           855.4691551999713             
4                -0.0           1665.942337400047
```

example df2:

```
        date BBG.XASX.AHG.S_price BBG.XASX.AHG.S_pos BBG.XASX.AHG.S_trade  \
0  2017-09-11            2.6068676                0.0                  0.0   
1  2017-09-12            2.6044785            76439.0              76439.0   
2  2017-09-13   2.6024171000000003            76439.0                  0.0   
3  2017-09-14            2.6139929            76439.0                  0.0   
4  2017-09-15            2.6602836            76439.0                  0.0   

   BBG.XASX.AHG.S_cost BBG.XASX.AHG.S_pnl_pre_cost 
0                 -0.0                         0.0   
1  -26.876303828302497                         0.0   
2                 -0.0          -157.5713545999606   
3                 -0.0           884.8425761999679   
4                 -0.0           3538.414817300014
```

example df 3:

```
  date BBG.XASX.AGL.S_price BBG.XASX.AGL.S_pos BBG.XASX.AGL.S_trade  \
0  2017-09-18           18.8195983                0.0                  0.0   
1  2017-09-19           18.5104704            40613.0              40613.0   
2  2017-09-20           18.2010515            40613.0                  0.0   
3  2017-09-21           18.2217768            40613.0                  0.0   
4  2017-09-22            17.840112            40613.0                  0.0   

  BBG.XASX.AGL.S_cost BBG.XASX.AGL.S_pnl_pre_cost 
0                -0.0                         0.0                          
1   -101.488374137952                         0.0    
2                -0.0          -12566.42978570005   
3                -0.0           841.7166089001112    
4                -0.0         -15500.552522399928
```

Adding together the example dataframes the code would return the following output:

output:

```
date                 1       2      3              4               5               6
11/09/2017   5.4372262       0      0              0               0               0
12/09/2017   5.4179974   76439  76439              2    -26.87630383               0
13/09/2017   5.3853445  163053  86614              4    -32.54046397    -157.5713546
14/09/2017   5.4067971  163053      0              6               0     1740.311731
15/09/2017   5.4723219  163053      0              8               0     5204.357155
18/09/2017  18.8195983       0      0              0               0               0
19/09/2017  18.5104704   40613  40613   -101.4883741               0               0
20/09/2017  18.2010515   40613      0              0    -12566.42979               0
21/09/2017  18.2217768   40613      0              0     841.7166089               0
22/09/2017   17.840112   40613      0              0    -15500.55252               0
```

All of the data-frames have the same number of columns in the same order. Please note in the output the dates in the individual df's can be different and I would like to see the totals for the individual days.

The code that I am generating all the individual `df` data-frames is:

```
for subdirname in glob.iglob('C:/Users/stacey/WorkDocs/tradeopt/'+filename+'//BBG*/tradeopt.is-pnl*.lzma', recursive=True):
    df = pd.DataFrame(numpy.zeros((0,27)))

    out = []
    with lzma.open(subdirname, mode='rt') as file:
        print(subdirname)
        for line in file:
            items = line.split(",")
            out.append(items)
            if len(out) > 0:
                a = pd.DataFrame(out[1:], columns=out[0])
```

How can I add together the individal df's into a sumdf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is convert column `date` to `DatetimeIndex` and `split` columns names by `.` to `MultiIndex`:

```
dfs = [] 
for subdirname in glob.iglob('C:/Users/stacey/WorkDocs/tradeopt/'+filename+'//BBG*/tradeopt.is-pnl*.lzma', recursive=True): 
    out = []
    with lzma.open(subdirname, mode='rt') as file:
        print(subdirname)
        for line in file:
            items = line.strip().split(",")
            out.append(items)
    if len(out) > 0:
        a = pd.DataFrame(out[1:], columns=out[0]).set_index('date')
        a.index = pd.to_datetime(a.index)  
        dfs.append(a)
```

And then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and `sum` by columns names:

```
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).sum(level=0, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael, I'm getting the  error 'ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>' associated with the line of code: df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).sum(level=[0,1,3], axis=1).  Any idea what might be causing the issue?

Comment: thanks, no the data is not confidential, would you like me to post it somewhere?

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, I'll send the files on later on if that's ok?